# Can't find out what symbol this is

Tags: words, questions, learning

[image]

Any help? I've tried finding out what this is but I've hit a wall. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the other form of the hiragana "ki" き.

Comment: So it's the same as using that?

Comment: Yeah it's the same symbol.